# VLOOKUP / CONCATENATE "#N/A" error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to put two columns together and then look up the value from another sheet.  If I hardcode the numbers the VLOOKUP works but with CONCATENATE I get `#N/A`.  Both columns are General format.  So I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

This is what I am doing, in Excel 2010:

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($W26,W$1),Sheet2!$A$1:$B$200,2,FALSE)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
=VLOOKUP(CONCATENATE($W26,W$1)+0,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$200,2,FALSE)
```

Someone sent this to me and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple comma at begin of cell

like '#N/A

It will treat column as String, and not as number

Answer (score -1):

concatenate cannot have a range, you can give a single cell or value in double quotation mark.  When you drag down the formula will change as per the request.

Comment: Not sure on what you are saying to do.  Can you do a quick sample of what you are asking me to do.  Sorry. Better way for me to understand and learn it better.  I am a visual learner.